# Grab input value inside array when button is clicked

Tags: reactjs

I want to grab the value of input inside the array when the button is clicked. How do i pass the input value to the function of button.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
export default function Todo(props) {

const [todo,settodo] = useState([]);

function getdata(){
  //fetch data
  settodo(data);
}


function SaveInput(id){

}

useEffect(() => {
   getdata();
},[]);

return (

    <React.Fragment>
        <div>
            {todo.map(function(item, key){
                return <div>
                    <div>{item.name}</div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="inputval" onChange={() => handleChange(e)}>
                        <button onClick={()=> SaveInput(item.id)}></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            })}
        </div>
    </React.Fragment>

)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send `item.id` to your `handleChange` function,

```
<input type="text" name="inputval" onChange={(e) => handleChange(e,item.id)} />
```

You `handleChange` function should,

```
const handleChange = (e,id) => {
  let val = e.target.value;
  setInputVal(prevState =>({
      ...prevState, 
      [id]:val
  }))
}
```

You must define a state to store input values,

```
const [inputVal,setInputVal] = useState({});
```

On the click of button you can access input state,

```
function SaveInput(id){
  console.log(inputVal[id]);
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vpbnux)

Answer (score 1):

You can save the inputs in a separate useState when the input is being changed, which can be later retrieved easily during the button click event.

Code below is an example and is not tested, but should give you some idea how to proceed.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
export default function Todo(props) {

const [todo,settodo] = useState([]);
const [inputVal, setInputVal] = useState({});

function getdata(){
  //fetch data
  settodo(data);
}


function SaveInput(id){
 let inputVal = inputVal[id];
 // do other stuff.
}

useEffect(() => {
   getdata();
},[]);

return (

    <React.Fragment>
        <div>
            {todo.map(function(item, key){
                return <div>
                    <div>{item.name}</div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" name="inputval" onChange={(e) => setInputVal({...inputVal, [item.id]: e.target.value })}>
                        <button onClick={()=> SaveInput(item.id)}></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            })}
        </div>
    </React.Fragment>

)
}
```

Comment: unable to type into the input field.

Answer (score 1):

One common pattern is to use the `handleChange(event)` function on `input` to set a state with the current value.

```
const [input,setInupt] = useState("");

function handleChange(event) {
    setInput(event.target.value)    
}
```

and when the button is clicked, you can use the value of the input state to pass on

```
<button onClick={()=> console.log(input))}>
```

Comment: unable to type into the input field.

Comment: remember to set input value attribute to state ```<input value={input} />```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, If you are having an onChange method then you must have a value for that input as well or else it will display a warning for "uncontrolled input" and that input box is of no use to you unless you provide a value to it.

Secondly, you should use a state for the values of those input boxes and then you can access the values of input in the save button click function. Here is the example of how you can do it.

```
import React from 'react'

export default class Todo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            inputIDs: {}
        }
    }

    SaveInput = id => {
        console.log("input value:", this.state[id]);
    };

    handleChange = (e, id) => {
        this.setState({[id]: e.target.value});
    };

    render() {
        const {inputIDs} = this.state;
        const todo = [
            {id: 1, val: "abc", name: "lorem"},
            {id: 2, val: "xyz", name: "Ipsum"}
        ];

        let todos = todo.map((item, key) => {
            return <div key={key}>
                <div>{item.name}</div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" value={this.state[item.id]} onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, item.id)}/>
                    <button onClick={() => this.SaveInput(item.id)}>Click Me!</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        });

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {todos}
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}
```